# What is wrong with this SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing a clean up of a database but I am getting this error. I was to delete data less than 6 months old.

Query:

```
Delete from dbo.Jobs 
where dtpDate <= '2016-04-27 15:23:00.000'
```

Error:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

The type is datetime

Comment: What is type of `dtpDate` ?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86313/conversion-of-a-varchar-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-out-of check this question

Comment: in order for us to properly answer your question, we need to know the format of dtpDate, so please do an echo of a date or two of type dtpDate so that we can compare the formats.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM dbo.Jobs 
      WHERE dtpDate <= CAST('2016-04-27 15:23:00.000' AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a cast to the query.

```
CAST( '2016-04-27 15:23:00.000' AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your server probably has date format settings that are incompatible with `yyyy-mm-dd`. Check your current `dateformat` setting with `dbcc useroptions`. If it is incorrect, then change it with `set dateformat`.

The best solution is to make all queries independent of the current date format, e.g.

- The ODBC locale-independent escape sequence

  ```
  delete from dbo.Jobs where dtpDate <= {ts'2016-04-27 15:23:00.000'}
  ```
- The ODBC `convert()` format

  ```
  delete from dbo.Jobs where dtpDate <= convert(datetime, '2016-04-27 15:23:00.000', 120)
  ```
- Use parameters when issuing SQL commands from an application.